# MiniEdit GUI Unable to export python file

Tags: python, mininet

Miniedit GUI is showing error (as given below) when trying to export l2 script. I am running the Miniedit python file as python 3.6 as it was showing errors when opening with default python installed 2.7.

Error message:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py"

TypeError: a byte -like object is required, not 'str'
```

[image: Screenshot of the full error message]

Answer (score 1):

Change the line 1452 to:

```
self.appPrefs.update(loadedTopology['application'])
```

And the lines 1686 and 1705 to:

```
f = open(fileName, 'w')
```

for more information [Fix python3 compatibility issues in miniedit](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/pull/1059)

Answer (score 0):

Go to where miniedit.py locate then open it with text editor.

Go to line 1702 and change to:

```py
f = open(fileName, 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, all I did was change the default file path to desktop `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mininet/examples` path to `Desktop` and it works,
so all you have to do is change the file path

Answer (score 0):

I used Python 2 to run Mininedit on Mininet 2.3.0, and it is working properly.

Command below:

```
$ sudo -E python2 ~/mininet/examples/miniedit.py
```